# Spark Window Functions: calculated once per frame/range?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is a question about Window Functions in Spark.

Assume I have this DF

```
DATE_S | ID | STR | VALUE
-------------------------
1      | 1  | A   | 0.5
1      | 1  | A   | 1.23
1      | 1  | A   | -0.4
2      | 1  | A   | 2.0
3      | 1  | A   | -1.2
3      | 1  | A   | 0.523
1      | 2  | A   | 1.0
2      | 2  | A   | 2.5
3      | 2  | A   | 1.32
3      | 2  | A   | -3.34
1      | 1  | B   | 1.5
1      | 1  | B   | 0.23
1      | 1  | B   | -0.3
2      | 1  | B   | -2.0
3      | 1  | B   | 1.32
3      | 1  | B   | 523.0
1      | 2  | B   | 1.3
2      | 2  | B   | -0.5
3      | 2  | B   | 4.3243
3      | 2  | B   | 3.332
```

This is just an example! Assume that there are **many more DATE_S for each (ID, STR)**, **many more IDs and STRs**, and many more entries per (DATE_S, ID, STR). Obviously there are multiple values per Combination (DATE_S, ID, STR)

Now I do this:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("ID", "STR").orderBy("DATE_S").rangeBetween(-N, -1)
df.withColumn("RESULT", function("VALUE").over(w))
```

where **N** might lead to the inclusion of a large range of rows, from 100 to 100000 and more, depending on ("ID", "STR")

The result will be something like this

```
DATE_S | ID | STR | VALUE | RESULT
----------------------------------
1      | 1  | A   | 0.5   | R1
1      | 1  | A   | 1.23  | R1
1      | 1  | A   | -0.4  | R1
2      | 1  | A   | 2.0   | R2
3      | 1  | A   | -1.2  | R3
3      | 1  | A   | 0.523 | R3
1      | 2  | A   | 1.0   | R4
2      | 2  | A   | 2.5   | R5
3      | 2  | A   | 1.32  | R6
3      | 2  | A   | -3.34 | R7
1      | 1  | B   | 1.5   | R8
1      | 1  | B   | 0.23  | R8
1      | 1  | B   | -0.3  | R9
2      | 1  | B   | -2.0  | R10
3      | 1  | B   | 1.32  | R11
3      | 1  | B   | 523.0 | R11
1      | 2  | B   | 1.3   | R12
2      | 2  | B   | -0.5  | R13
3      | 2  | B   | 4.3243| R14
3      | 2  | B   | 3.332 | R14
```

There are identical "RESULT"s because for every row with identical (DATE_S, ID, ST), the values that go into the calculation of "function" are the same.

**My question is this:**

Does spark **call "function" for each ROW** (recalculating the same value multiple times) **or calculate it once per range (frame?)** of values and just pastes them on all rows that fall in the range?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: may be an idea to show the calculation...

Comment: Do you think it is important, especially for the first question? I was actually just trying to phrase the question more generall. Two things I am doing: 1) avg 2) callUDF("percentile", col("VALUE"), typedLit(Array(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)))

Comment: I edited the post to reflect that my main point of interest at the moment is question 1)

Comment: i just refreshed myself on percentiles, many eons ago at university stats. the range seems small.

Comment: the range is just to illustrate the problem and because I did not want to make an example df with a range of 90 with about 100-10000 entries per DATE_S. this is first and foremost NOT about the actual RESULT of "very_expensive_operation"

Comment: OK, then to me there is no issue. the main point is that the window does not go to a single partition and hence single worker. it is fine. I will post on this. but the udf is percentile? pls confirm

Comment: too many questions to answer with a risk of a downvote.

Comment: I have refrased the original post. Also, this is not about an "issue" or a "problem". Basically I just want to know if spark calculates window functions multiple times over an identical frame/range, or of it somehow knows the result will be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your data the result may not be the same if run twice from what I can see as there is no distinct ordering possibility. But we leave that aside.

Whilst there is codegen optimization, it is nowhere to be found that it checks in the way you state for if the next invocation is the same set of data to process for the next row. I have never read of that type of optimization. There is fusing due to lazy evaluation approach, but that is another matter. So, per row it calculates again.

From a great source: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-windows.html

> ... At its core, a window function calculates a return value for every
>   input row of a table based on a group of rows, called the frame. Every
>   input row can have a unique frame associated with it. ...
>
> ... In other words, when executed, a window function computes a value
>   for each and every row in a window (per window specification). ...

The biggest issue is to have suitable number of partitions for parallel processing, which is expensive, but this is big data. `partitionBy("ID", "STR")`  is the clue here and that is a good thing.

Comment: Thank you for your insight and the link! This is actually a great source

You are correct, a distinct ordering is not possible. However, if "operation" does not depend on the ordering (1 + 2 = 2 + 1), this should not matter. But I see the point, spark has no way of knowing if "operation" depens on the order. But it could know for built ins like sum or avg (which kinda sorta do not depend on the order, as long as we ignore floating point errors)

Comment: Success, if you look at some of my other answers you will see I go down the road of this type of thing. You can even get around some problems.